# Dropdown doesn't work in a loop but normal

Tags: reactjs, loops, react-hooks

I am making a dropdown accordion. After adapting my code to the example bellow, everything works fine:

Example: https://codepen.io/CreativeBulma/pen/YbQqoQ

trainingData

```
[{
    "von": "17:00",
    "bis": "18:00",
    "tag": "Mittwoch",
    "trainingsid": 46
},
{
    "von": "19:00",
    "bis": "21:00",
    "tag": "Donnerstag",
    "trainingsid": 51
}]
```

That's how it works:

```
 <div ref={collapsiblesRef} id={`accordion_first2`}>
                        
                            <div className="card">
                                <header className="card-header">
                                    <p className="card-header-title">
                                        montaj
                                    </p>
                                    <a href={`#collapsible-card-0`} data-action="collapse" className="card-header-icon is-hidden-fullscreen" aria-label="more options">
                                        <span className="icon">
                                            <i className="fas fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </header>
                                <div id={`collapsible-card-0`} className="is-collapsible" data-parent={`accordion_first2`}>
                                    <div className="card-content">
                                        <p className="is-small has-text-primary has-text-weight-semibold">Tag</p>

                                        <input className="input mb-5" style={{ width: "33%" }} type="text" placeholder="Wochentag" />
                                        <p className="is-small has-text-primary has-text-weight-semibold">Uhrzeit von</p>
                                        <input className="input mb-5" style={{ width: "33%" }} type="text" placeholder="Uhrzeit von" />

                                        <p className="is-small has-text-primary has-text-weight-semibold">Uhrzeit bis</p>
                                        <input className="input mb-5" style={{ width: "33%" }} type="text" placeholder="Uhrzeit bis" />

                                        <article className="message mt-3">
                                            <div className="message-body">
                                                Uhrzeit von ist die Startzeit und Uhrzeit bis ist die Endzeit des Trainings. Gültiges Format hh:mm, z.B. 17:45.
                                            </div>
                                        </article>


                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="card">
                                <header className="card-header">
                                    <p className="card-header-title">
                                        dasdasd
                                    </p>
                                    <a href={`#collapsible-card-1`} data-action="collapse" className="card-header-icon is-hidden-fullscreen" aria-label="more options">
                                        <span className="icon">
                                            <i className="fas fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </header>
                                <div id={`collapsible-card-1`} className="is-collapsible" data-parent={`accordion_first2`}>
                                    <div className="card-content">
                                        <p className="is-small has-text-primary has-text-weight-semibold">Tag</p>

                                        <input className="input mb-5" style={{ width: "33%" }} type="text" placeholder="Wochentag" />
                                        <p className="is-small has-text-primary has-text-weight-semibold">Uhrzeit von</p>
                                        <input className="input mb-5" style={{ width: "33%" }} type="text" placeholder="Uhrzeit von" />

                                        <p className="is-small has-text-primary has-text-weight-semibold">Uhrzeit bis</p>
                                        <input className="input mb-5" style={{ width: "33%" }} type="text" placeholder="Uhrzeit bis" />

                                        <article className="message mt-3">
                                            <div className="message-body">
                                                Uhrzeit von ist die Startzeit und Uhrzeit bis ist die Endzeit des Trainings. Gültiges Format hh:mm, z.B. 17:45.
                                            </div>
                                        </article>


                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>
```

Since I am having several elements I want to add to the dropdown, I am using a loop. But unfortunately, after adding the loop, the collapsibles aren't working properly - they are staying open and I cannot close them or interact with them.

So that's actually what I want:

```
                <div ref={collapsiblesRef} id={`accordion_first`}>
                    {trainingData.map((d, i) => (
                        <div className="card" key={i}>
                            <header className="card-header">
                                <p className="card-header-title">
                                    {d.tag}
                                </p>
                                <a href={`#collapsible-card-${i}`} data-action="collapse" className="card-header-icon is-hidden-fullscreen" aria-label="more options">
                                    <span className="icon">
                                        <i className="fas fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </header>
                            <div id={`collapsible-card-${i}`} className="is-collapsible" data-parent={`accordion_first`}>
                                <div className="card-content">
                                    <p className="is-small has-text-primary has-text-weight-semibold">Tag</p>

                                        </div>*/}
                                    <input className="input mb-5" style={{ width: "33%" }} type="text" placeholder="Wochentag" />
                                    <p className="is-small has-text-primary has-text-weight-semibold">Uhrzeit von</p>
                                    <input className="input mb-5" style={{ width: "33%" }} type="text" placeholder="Uhrzeit von" />

                                    <p className="is-small has-text-primary has-text-weight-semibold">Uhrzeit bis</p>
                                    <input className="input mb-5" style={{ width: "33%" }} type="text" placeholder="Uhrzeit bis" />

                                    <article className="message mt-3">
                                        <div className="message-body">
                                            Uhrzeit von ist die Startzeit und Uhrzeit bis ist die Endzeit des Trainings. Gültiges Format hh:mm, z.B. 17:45.
                                        </div>
                                    </article>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    ))}

                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played a bit with the code, this works for me.

```
import React from "react";
import bulmaCollapsible from '@creativebulma/bulma-collapsible';
import 'bulma';
import '@creativebulma/bulma-collapsible';


///I want to generate a random number of collapsibles.
const array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

class Collapsibles extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.collapsibles = bulmaCollapsible.attach(".is-collapsible", {
      container: this.refs.collapsibles
    });
  }

  

  render() {

    const collapsibles = array.map((c,i) => <article className="message">
    <div className="message-header">
      <p>
        Question 1{" "}
        <a href={"#collapsible-message-accordion-"+ i.toString()} data-action="collapse">
          Collapse/Expand
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div
      id={"collapsible-message-accordion-"+ i.toString()}
      className="message-body is-collapsible is-active"
      data-parent="accordion_first"
    >
      <div className="message-body-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.{" "}
        <strong>Pellentesque risus mi</strong>, tempus quis placerat ut,
        porta nec nulla. Vestibulum rhoncus ac ex sit amet fringilla.
        Nullam gravida purus diam, et dictum
        <a>felis venenatis</a> efficitur. Aenean ac{" "}
        <em>eleifend lacus</em>, in mollis lectus. Donec sodales, arcu et
        sollicitudin porttitor, tortor urna tempor ligula, id porttitor mi
        magna a neque. Donec dui urna, vehicula et sem eget, facilisis
        sodales sem.
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>)
    return (
      <div ref="collapsibles" id="accordion_first">
        
        {collapsibles}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Collapsibles
```

A few notes on the code:

1. First, I assume you're aware that `bulmaCollapsible` is an `npm` package that needs to be installed. You can find directions for installation [here](https://bulma-collapsible.netlify.app/installation/).
2. I didn't fully understand where you got your code from, I copied mine from the CodePen you provided. Each collapsible container is an `article` tag.
3. My code lacks any `transition` properties. So it won't slowly open and close. You'll have to add some minor css to make that happen.
4. The method `attach` is responsible to initialise any element with the className of `is-collapsible`. It was made so you can initialise multiple collapsibles at once.
5. In my code I created an array `const` called "array". Then I used the `map` method like you did to generate multiple collapsibles.
6. The following will give you 1 collapsible:

   ```
    <article className="message">
    <div className="message-header">
      <p>
        Question 1{" "}
        <a href={"#collapsible-message-accordion-"+ i.toString()} data-action="collapse">
          Collapse/Expand
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div
      id={"collapsible-message-accordion-"+ i.toString()}
      className="message-body is-collapsible is-active"
      data-parent="accordion_first"
    >
      <div className="message-body-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.{" "}
        <strong>Pellentesque risus mi</strong>, tempus quis placerat ut,
        porta nec nulla. Vestibulum rhoncus ac ex sit amet fringilla.
        Nullam gravida purus diam, et dictum
        <a>felis venenatis</a> efficitur. Aenean ac{" "}
        <em>eleifend lacus</em>, in mollis lectus. Donec sodales, arcu et
        sollicitudin porttitor, tortor urna tempor ligula, id porttitor mi
        magna a neque. Donec dui urna, vehicula et sem eget, facilisis
        sodales sem.
      </div>
    </div>
   ```
7. Each collapsible needs to have a unique id. For each collapsible we use an `a` tag with an `href` attribute equal to the collapsible's id. This is reflected in the lines where you see `href={"#collapsible-message-accordion-"+ i.toString()}` and `id={"#collapsible-message-accordion-"+ i.toString()}`

To know more about how this package work, visit their [JS API](https://bulma-collapsible.netlify.app/javascript/) page.

Comment: I have taken all your comments into account. 
However, it does not work with my `trainingsData`, why does it not work with the array and does work with your simple array?

Comment: If you take my code and replace array.map with trainingData.map without changing anything else, does it work? Meaning does it show functioning collapsibles?

Comment: Yes, I used your code. When I use `trainingsData`, the code no longer works.

Comment: Is trainingData a local variable or is it fetched from a database?

Comment: Fetched from a database, but the loop works without problems if I only display the day, for example.

Comment: try to do this >> {trainingData && trainingData.length && trainingData.length > 0 ? trainingData.map(THE_FULL_CODE) : null} so check if traininData is defined and if its length is above 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237868/discussion-between-nizar-and-mr-hankey).